# clearcase - License checkout error

Tags: clearcase

Rational ClearCase is freshly installed on a Linux server. Also started the the Rational RLKS license server as "`root`".

When running any ClearCase command as a non-root user on the server, below error message occurs:

```
#cleartool lsview
cleartool: Error: **License checkout error from Rational Common     Licensing:
License server system does not support this feature.**

Feature:       ClearCase

License path:  /var/adm/rational/clearcase/config/flexlm_host:

FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147

For further information, refer to the FLEXnet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".

cleartool: Error: You do not have a license to run ClearCase.
#
```

The `lmutil` utility shows that the Rational License Administrator starts successfully. Still the license is unable to be checked-out by any non-root user.

```
/opt/IBM/RationalRLKS/bin#./lmutil lmstat -a -c
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2011 Flexera Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Flexible License Manager status on Mon 3/30/2015 09:37
License server status: 27000@127.0.0.1
    License file(s) on 127.0.0.1: /opt/IBM/RationalRLKS/config/server_license.lic:/opt/IBM/RationalRLKS/config/rational_server_temp.dat: /opt/IBM/RationalRLKS/config/rational_server_perm.dat:
 127.0.0.1: license server UP (MASTER) v11.10
Vendor daemon status (on 127.0.0.1):
   ibmratl: UP v11.10
    Feature usage info:
  rational: UP v11.10
Feature usage info:
Users of MultiSite:  **(Total of 2 licenses issued;  Total of 0 licenses in use)**
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [main FlexLM errors listed at this IBM page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Wa5f0e71b4f3c_4bc8_adb1_be13c9277040/page/Troubleshoot).

A [similar one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295879) applies when ClearCase is installed as a stand alone product and not as part of the Suite products.

There must be an incompatibility between the particular brand of ClearCase you have installed and the licenses proposes by the license server.

Check also the [requirements for the RLKS (IBM Rational License Key Server)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24035648#PREREQ), and double-check that your ClearCase product key does come from the [IBM License Key Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/support/licensing/).

Comment: Thanks for your response Von. However I am unable to fix it. the license server 8.1.4 is latest and Clearcase installed is version 8.0.0.13 . the product key comes straight from the IBM License key centre and have generated it myself. The lmutil output as stated above shows the acceptance of license and accepts the key. Am not sure why its failing on checkout licenses.

Comment: @SaurabhPorwal IBM support should be able to troubleshoot that, checking first if the RLKS is compatible with your old ClearCase 8.0.x.